# Are Javascript/Cookies enabled or disabled?

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

I am looking for some code that will return me values if the user has JavaScript enabled or disabled, as well as cookies.

I know this is probably easy to do, but my time constraints are so tight, it hurts.  There has to be something out there using php that does this.  Ideally I would love to find code that has a page setup with all the possible values that could affect my scripts.

**EDIT:** Obviously JavaScript may be disabled, but, I am hoping that I can find something out there to test the two cases.

**My Solution**

For anoyone else looking for code to detect if the users has cookie enabled or disabled, here is what I ended up coming up with from the posts below... you can just drop this at teh top of any page and it works...

```
<?php
// do a cookie test
if (!isset($_SESSION['cookie_check']))
{
    if (!isset($_GET['cc']))
    {
        // drop a cookie in their bag
        setcookie("cookiecheck", "ok", time()+3600);
        header("Location: ".$common->selfURL()."?cc=1");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        // do we have a problem?
        if (@$_COOKIE['cookiecheck'] != "ok")
        {
            // we have a problem
            header("Location: /site-diag.php");
            exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['cookie_check'] = true;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You also want to test for Java?

Comment: I was thinking about making a red box saying "Java Disabled" and if java is enabled, simply replace it with a green box...

Comment: Does your site use both Java and JavaScript?

Comment: nope, just javascript... so easy for me to just say java... I meant javascript, sorry ;)

Answer (score -6, accepted):

First, realize that you can't use JavaScript to check for cookies if JavaScript is turned off. The usual check for cookies being on is to write one and then read it.

Do you care about the case when cookies are on but JavaScript is off? What are you going to do based on the information?

I found [this code here](http://www.zend.com/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=3395&S=b572f672884f726b08674ebf55ea152d) for checking for a cookie via PHP. Doesn't rely on JavaScript. Is PHP your server language?

```
<?php
class cookieCheck
{

    public function check()
    {
        if (setcookie("test", "test", time() + 100))
        {
            //COOKIE IS SET 
            if (isset ($_COOKIE['test']))
            {
                return "Cookies are enabled on your browser";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Cookies are <b>NOT</b> enabled on your browser";
            }
        }

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't you have to do a redirect before reading the cookie you're setting with setcookie()?  If my memory is working right, the first time you run this code you will get the 'NOT enabled' response, but if you were to refresh it would show that the cookie is set.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [jQuery cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie) to write a cookie and then see if you can read it back again.  That would tell you if cookies were enabled in the client's browser or not.

Comment: If JavaScript was enabled it would. :-)

Answer (score 2):

For checking Javascript, either they have it or they don't. If not, you can use `<noscript>` tags to display a message asking them to turn it on, put a meta redirect inside, etc. That is the extent of your testing ability.

As for cookies, just try setting a cookie then reading it back! Since you're concerned about Javascript's ability to handle cookies, I assume you already have a cookie library that you are using, meaning that you can just use the `set` function for a test cookie then the `get` function to read it back. If the test cookie can't be read back, cookies are off.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one for checking cookies

http://techpatterns.com/downloads/javascript_check_cookies.php

Answer (score 1):

if javascript is disabled then you can't use jquery or prototype.

write a function that writes a cookie, then tries to read it.

and secondly puts out some js code to the screen that makes a ajax call to a basic php script.

you can use a database to set the boolean results of both tests on the visitor table if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I check if cookies and JavaScript are enabled:

```
if($_SESSION['JSexe']) { // 3rd check js
    if($_COOKIE['JS']) {
        setcookie('JS','JS',time()-1); // check on every page load
    }
    else {
        header('Location: js.html');
    }
}
// 2nd so far it's been server-side scripting. Client-side scripting must be executed once to set second cookie.
// Without JSexe, user with cookies and js enabled would be sent to js.html the first page load.
elseif($_COOKIE['PHP']) {
    $_SESSION['JSexe'] = true;
}
else { //1st check cookies
    if($_GET['cookie']) {
        header('Location: cookies.html');
    }
    else{
        setcookie('PHP','PHP');
        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'?cookie=1');
    }
}
```

Explained in detail here: http://asdlog.com/Check_if_cookies_and_javascript_are_enable